# Showing the set of conjugacy classes of G forms a partition of G

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have in my proof something like
Let $$x \in G$$ The orbit of x orbit of x is $$<x> ={x \wedge g : g \in G}={g^{-1} x g:g\in G}$$

Hence the conjugacy class of G forms a partition of G.
What does this mean?

Comment: Show that if any two conjugacy classes intersect, than they are the same. This is the definition of *partition*

Answer (score 0):

It means there are elements $g_1,g_2, \dots g_n$ such that $G$ is the union of the conjugacy classes $\langle g_i \rangle$ and $ \langle g_i \rangle \cap \langle g_j \rangle = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$. So we have "partitioned" the set $G$ into disjoint sets.